# Recommended approaches for localizing data

Tags: database, database-design, localization, attributes, translation

We have number of entities that require localization into several languages, example:

```
A TEAM has a NAME and an ABBREVIATION.
A PRODUCT has a NAME and a DESCRIPTION
```

Up until now we've been creating a localized version of each table with the localizable fields as well as a culture. So for the **Product** table we would have a **LocalizedProduct** table as well.

It works, but as you can imagine the number of tables and entities grow and it's becoming increasingly frustrating creating admin interfaces all these objects.

I'm considering changing to an EAV (Entity/Attribute/Value) approach where instead, so all these localized texts would be stored as attributes on an entity and the table fields would be properties. The entity would then be localizable.

However I'm a bit wary about this approach as I've previously implemented EAV's and know that there are a lot of other issues relating to this approach (hard to query data, difficult to enforce constraints in database, needs a lot of work to handle data validation, etc.)

I'd like to hear from others who've done data localization, what approach have you taken?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to design your database as if for a single language, but add one table:

```
localization (keytext PK, language PK, translated)
```

Now, when you need a translation, you can join with this table per field you want translated, e.g.:

```
SELECT prod.id, prodname.translated AS name, proddesc.translated AS description
FROM product prod
INNER JOIN localization prodname ON prod.name = prodname.keytext AND prodname.language = 'en'
INNER JOIN localization proddesc ON prod.description = proddesc.keytext AND proddesc.language = 'en'
```

If you're concerned about incomplete translations, change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and COALESCE the translated text with the original.

The only trick with this is that your original text needs to be identifying, e.g. if you had a product and team with the same name, you'd get the same translation.  Naming conventions can be useful here.